# Why does my incoming HiddenService IP (Whonix) occasionally showing up on the ban list?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Using Whonix, just recently running a full bitcoin node (v0.15.1; Qt v5.3.2), on my peers list my incoming connection(s), HiddenService IP (10.152.152.10/xx) occasionally shows up on the ban list effectively killing my node status, why on earth under what circumstance(s) would this be occurring?

As of this most recent edit for example, I was working on my laptop this am where the node is running, had 5 inbound and usual 8 outbound then I went to check and what do I see? my 10.152.152.10 IP is on the ban list, wth?

Comment: It sounds like this "ban list" is a part of (or associated with) your desktop operating system (whonix) -- Not sure this is answerable here.